# MS Access application with SQL Server DB getting type mismatch error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I converted an Access app to use a SQL Server Database on the back end and now I am having type mismatch issues in some of the queries.

I am fairly new to Access and could really use some help.

This is the SQL script to one of the queries having the type mismatch error:

```
SELECT [Projected Timeline].[Site ID]
     , [tblCHIMasterSite].[Name]
     , [tblCHIMasterSite].[City]
     , [tblCHIMasterSite].[State]
     , [Projected Timeline].[Site Model]
FROM [Projected Timeline] 
INNER JOIN [tblCHIMasterSite] ON [Projected Timeline].[Site ID] = [tblCHIMasterSite].[SiteID]
```

I believe the error is from the comparison of [Site ID] = [SiteID].
The data types for site ID in both tables is int and this scrip works fine in SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Any ideas would be much appreciated...

Comment: Could you provide error log to better understanding?

Comment: Works fine on my testing here - only possible issues I can see are possibilities of using a reserved word "Name" as a field, but your bracketing of the field should be fine, and possibly fieldname "SiteID" without space [Site ID], is a typo error?

Comment: Could you give a try with CInt `ON CInt([Projected Timeline].[Site ID]) = CInt([tblCHIMasterSite].[SiteID])`

Comment: If you try to run this query in Access query-builder it works fine?

Comment: Verify the tables are linked properly in access.  I have had to refresh a link before because of weird stuff like this.